# Параметры адаптера

Tags: c#

Доброго времени суток! Я изучаю С# относительно недавно... В книжке (Библия C#) прочитал такой пример:

```
adapter.DeleteCommand = new OleDbCommand("Delete from Peoples WHERE idKey = ?");
adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("idKey", OleDbType.Integral, 10, "idKey");
adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = connection;
adapter.Update(dataset.Tables[0]);
```

объясните мне пожалуйста, где тут происходит передача значения ключу idKey? Я так и не понял, где это происходит, чтобы удалить определенную запись... В adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add ничего подобного не происходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае значение параметру не передаётся.
Вам нужно использовать либо [OleDbParameter.AddWithValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.addwithvalue(v=vs.90).aspx), либо делать так:
    adapter.DeleteCommand = new OleDbCommand("Delete from Peoples WHERE idKey = ?");
    OleDbParameter param = adapter.DeleteCommand.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "idKey";
    param.OleDbType = OleDbType.Integer;
    param.Value = 10; // передаём значение
    adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add(param);
    adapter.DeleteCommand.Connection = connection;
    adapter.Update(dataset.Tables[0]);

Comment: вот это пример! Спасибо, все понятно стало.

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я помню, значение параметра подставится вместо знака вопроса в запросе.

// 10 - это значение параметра
adapter.DeleteCommand.Parameters.Add("idKey", OleDbType.Integral, 10, "idKey");

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: А откуда берется значение параметра? В данном коде я не увидел этого.

Comment: обновил ответ.